# Trying to run JUnit 4.10 tests from RAD 7.5 getting exception

Tags: java, junit, rad

I am trying to run JUnit 4 tests from a JUnit 3 runner.  I have tried everything I can find and still cannot get it to run.  The latest error I am getting is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter incompatible with junit.framework.TestCase
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
package com.bcbst.junittest;

import junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter;
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({JUnitTestCase.class})

public class AllTests {

    public static Test suite() {
        return new JUnit4TestAdapter(JUnitTestCase.class);
    }

}
```

I am using RAD 7.5.5.3.

Is there a way to change RAD to use JUnit 4 instead of JUnit 3?  I'm stuck with the version of RAD I've got now.  The JUnit 4 jar is in my classpath, and it is the first entry there.  But it is using the runner packaged with RAD, which looks like it is using JUnit 3.2.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace please? And can you tell us how you're running the tests, through Eclipse maven, whatever, and the versions involved. Can you tell us if JUnitTestCase is defined as a JUnit 3 test or 4 test as well please? It looks like it's a JUnit 3 test. Also for JUnit 4 suites you don't need to define the suite() method.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and see if the workaround helps you

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363984

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Isn't that exactly what he does have?

Comment: @Matthew, I don't have a RAD 7.5 with me but the technotes states the workaround for this problem. Am i reading the technote incorrectly?

Comment: Yeah but reading the solution you posted it seems like it's what he already has